# ask jinja if a profile exists

Tags: python, django, jinja2

How can I check if the object in profile model does not exist in the database, the crearprofile button appears and if it exists, profile appears?

```
{% if user.profile.is_defined %}
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' user.id %}">Perfil</a>
{% else %}                  
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'crearprofile' %}">Crear perfil</a>
{% endif %}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIYxV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to define the User model instead use the default: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

With the authentication configured as in the link above, then you can create a computed property on `User` model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    # some fields
    ...

    # some methods
    ...

    @property
    def profile(self):
        try:
            return Profile.objects.get(user=self)
        except:
            return None


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
```

Then on Jinja template only check

```py
{% if user.profile %}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, but I can't edit it, it's for a course exercise, I have to find another way

Comment: maybe I can create a buttonprofile view and check if the profile exists, show it, and if not go to Profileform